# How to manage coupons codes?

Tags: php, algorithm, symfony

I generate unique codes to use them as coupon codes. This is how a coupon code is generated

```
public function generateCoupon(){
    $chars = "0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    $res = "";

    for ($i = 0; $i < 6; $i++) {
        $res .= $chars[mt_rand(0, strlen($chars) - 1)];
    }

    return $res;
}
```

To ensure that I don't have the same code multiple times in DB I check if the generated code exists:

```
$coupon = $this->generateCoupon();

while($repository->findOneByCode($coupon) != null){
    $coupon = $this->generateCoupon();
}
```

A coupon code is requested by a user and it is assigned to the user until it is used.

What should happen to the coupon when it is used? Now the code is deleted from DB and it can be used again. Is this good practice? Or should I store the code forever? How would you manage your coupons?

Comment: @sje397 can you give more detail pls

Comment: just use a bool column named active

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use an [UUID](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuid) as your coupon code, to ensure uniqueness, or store the coupon code in a record "forever", marked as used.

Comment: If the coupon is used, does it make sense to generate and use it again?  Maybe it will be randomly generated again and I have the same coupon twice, with different uuid...

Comment: @artworkad Option 1: You would generate the UUID as the copon code in the first place, store it until used and then delete the UUID (=coupon code). Option 2: You generate the coupon code as in your example and store it in a database. When it's used, you mark it as used in the database, and further use of it will be invalid. Option 2 make no used of UUIDs.